# Not common IP address

Tags: php, networking, ip

I have a problem when I'm trying to parse the **visitor IP**, **1 / 500 users** had a bad IP as you can see in the logs.
Can someone explain to me if I make a mistake in my code?

**My code:**

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip = str_replace(' ','', $ip);

if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === false){
    Log::error('IP : '.$ip);
    return Redirect::to($link->white_url, 301);
}
```

**Logs :**

```
[2017-03-23 16:36:15] production.ERROR: IP : 192.168.5.173,sams04818.orl,sams04818.orl  
[2017-03-23 16:36:30] production.ERROR: IP : 192.168.5.173,sams04818.orl,sams04818.orl  
[2017-03-23 16:37:15] production.ERROR: IP : 192.168.4.217,wmt03459.chi,wmt03459.chi  
[2017-03-23 16:39:01] production.ERROR: IP : 77.154.224.155,77.154.224.155  
[2017-03-23 17:31:03] production.ERROR: IP : 192.168.5.80,mcd03610.phx,mcd03610.phx  
[2017-03-23 17:09:09] production.ERROR: IP : 92.90.16.110,92.90.16.110
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver `192.168.5.173,sams04818.orl,sams04818.orl` is a bad IP, it contains extra text after the IP.

Comment: Are you running your own reverse proxy or load balancer? If not, you can't trust headers like `X-Forwarded-For` or `Client-IP`.

Comment: Can I have explication instead of down vote ? ...

Comment: It looks like all the bad IPs have a comma after the IP. You could simply remove everything starting from comma.

Comment: @Barmar I don't use Proxy or something else. I will check this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) header would contain multiple IP addresses if the client request has passed through multiple proxies. XFF is also commonly used by load balancers.

The first IP address in the string, however, belongs to the origin. You could extract it.

```
if(strpos($ip,','))
    $ip = substr($ip, 0, strpos($ip,','));
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format

Comment: Good answer, but replace all that code with `$ip = strstr("$ip,", ",", true);`